# Why doesn't my product review on Amazon show all photos?

Tags: amazon

I wrote a review to a product I bought last week, and just posted a review yesterday. The thing is I uploaded like 8 or 9 photos of my item, and only 3 appear on my review. (This is the same in a mobile or desktop browser.)

Why is that happening? How can I get all of my photos to appear?

I am providing screen shots of my screen so you can better understand.

[image: screen shot 1]

[image: screen shot 2]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently it started showing all the pictures I don't know what happened...

I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens on every single review I write for Amazon. Very rarely will all of the photos show up. A few times none of them have shown up. Sometimes simply resubmitting the review will fix the glitch. It doesn't have anything to do with the number of photos being submitted. It can be 2 or 12, the same thing happens. I've tried Chrome on PC and mobile and Edge. Makes no difference. And Amazon Help is not helpful at all about the issue. It's especially frustrating because you take the time to take the photos, crop, resize them, etc, and then nobody can even see them.

Comment: Yeah thanks mate. It seems they check and evaluate each photo separately, and after some time they finally appear...